# oracle sql count from different table

Tags: sql, oracle

I've two Table with Below Data:

1) Trans Table

```
TICKET  STATUS
56       0
56       0
```

2) Resa Table

```
R_TICKET    R_STATUS
56            0
```

I want result like this if the ticket count in both the table matches then print `0` else `1`.

I've tried below query but it does not work

```
select case when count(a.ticket) = count(b.r_ticket) 
            then 0 
            else 1 
       end as result 
from trans a, resa b
```

it shows `0` but it should be `1` because count of ticket `56` is `2` in `trans` and `1` in `resa`.

Some changes in question:
I want Result like this:

```
TICKET  Count(Ticket) r_Ticket  Count(r_Ticket) result
56       2               56           1           1
58       1               58           1           0
```

Comment: The question is not clear. What is the "ticket count"? In your first table you have a single ticket, 56. Do you mean "row count" rather than "ticket count"? What if in the tables there are more than one ticket number - are you counting all the rows in the tables? All the rows grouped by ticket number? All distinct tickets in the tables? Is the result a comparison between the tables, or a comparison by ticket number? (The counts are equal for ticket 56, different for ticket 58, etc.?)

Comment: ticket number can be different, i want ticket count should be matched, like for an example in first table ticket number 56 is repeated two times and in second table it is reapeated 1 time so it is mismatch it should print 1. But if another ticket suppose 58 is repeated in 2 times in first table and also 2 times in second table it matched should print 0.

Comment: Then @Tim Biegeleisen's solution is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.ticket, t2.ticket),
       CASE WHEN t1.count = t2.count THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS match
FROM
(
    SELECT TICKET AS ticket, COUNT(*) AS tcount
    FROM Trans
    GROUP BY TICKET
) t1
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT R_TICKET AS ticket, COUNT(*) AS tcount
    FROM Resa
    GROUP BY R_TICKET
) t2
    ON t1.ticket = t2.ticket
```

Comment: Please check the proper Oracle syntax (and I suspect SQL Standard syntax) for WITH clause, when you have more than one CTE.

Comment: @mathguy I didn't know about Oracle's cte restrictions.  Instead I just used direct subqueries.  Less flavor, more code.

Comment: I don't know what Oracle CTE restrictions you mean. Oracle implements the SQL Standard syntax for CTEs. When you have more than one, you separate them with a comma, you don't write WITH again. Is there a DBMS you use more frequently, where that is the correct syntax? (Sorry, I only know Oracle.) Other than that, WITH clauses are a great tool.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use commas in the `from` clause.  This is wrong in this case anyway . . . if one of the tables is empty, you'll get an empty intermediate result set before the aggregation.

Instead, use subqueries to get the counts:

```
select (case when a.cnt = b.cnt then 0 else 1
        end) as result 
from (select count(*) as cnt from trans) a
cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt from resa b);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Actually i dont want row wise count to match, i want count of ticket number should be matched.